# Safe way to check if a property of an object contains a substring

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a variable `v` in my program, and I want to check if its property `p` contains a sub string `sub`. I could write a code like follows:

```
if (v.p.indexOf('sub') !== -1) {
    // do something here
}
```

However, I have some doubts when seeing this code:

1. What if `v` is never declared
2. What if the property `p` does not exist in `v`?
3. What if `v.p` is `null` or `undefined`?
4. What if `v.p` is not a string

I want all the above cases not to raise errors in my code, and only `do something here` when `v.p` exists and contains a string that contains `sub`.

Does anyone know how to write this code correctly?

Comment: You can use lodash _.get function. Or use try...catch

Comment: Thank you... But I prefer raw typescript or javascript code...

Comment: In TS you can use v?.p?.indexOf...

Comment: I'm writing TypeScript, if you are sure about `v?.p?.indexOf`, please post an answer...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html Optional chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TS you can use "Optional chaining"

For example

`let x = foo?.bar.baz();`

this is a way of saying that when foo is defined, foo.bar.baz() will be computed; but when foo is null or undefined, stop what we’re doing and just return undefined.”

More plainly, that code snippet is the same as writing the following.

```
let x = (foo === null || foo === undefined) ?
    undefined :
    foo.bar.baz();
```

See more https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html Optional chaining

Comment: `foo?.bar.baz()` will return `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'foo'.`  For optional chaining foo must not be `undefined`

Comment: add a note about typeof foo for undeclared variables.  especially if you're already doing TS, it should never be allowed, and your linter should force rejection

Comment: note that use this `?` when you are 100% sure it is typescript; t silently has trouble in JavaScript code.